# Проблема с регулярным выражением PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, perl

Имеем строку к примеру:

```
Описание работы 4

[gallery ids="781,780"]
```

Отсюда нужно достать IDшники

Я пытаюсь получить их c помощью следующего выражения:

`$ids = preg_replace('@.*\[gallery ids="([0-9,]+?)"]@m', '$1', $post->post_content);`

В моем понимании должно получиться 781,780, но что-то пошло не так... Я понимаю проблема в переносах строки, но флаг `m` я использую. В общем у кого есть версии, что не так? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то Вам нужно так (если только один ИД):

```
preg_match('/\[gallery ids="([^"]+)"\]/', $input_line, $output_array);
```

В $output_array[1] будет 781,780
или если несколько

```
preg_match_all('/\[gallery ids="([^"]+)"\]/', $input_lines, $output_array);
```

то в $output_array[1] будут все ИД

preg_replace - он заменяет в тексте по регулярному выражению, т.е. делает совсем другое

Comment: Супер. спасибо то что нужно :)  Я не правильно представлял себе работу preg_replace